# generic serde_json deserialize function for strongly typed objects

Tags: rust

This function is from the serde_json docs :

```
fn read_user_from_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<User, Box<dyn Error>> {
    // Open the file in read-only mode with buffer.
    let file = File::open(path)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    // Read the JSON contents of the file as an instance of `User`.
    let u = serde_json::from_reader(reader)?;

    // Return the `User`.
    Ok(u)
}
```

I want to make it more generic so I can deserialize to any typed object. Then, I can use the function for multiple objects.

```
fn read_user_from_file<T,P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>> {
    // Open the file in read-only mode with buffer.
    let file = File::open(path)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let t:T = serde_json::from_reader(reader)?;

    // Return the `User`.
    Ok(t)
}
```

However The error message on the  `serde_json::from_reader` line is :

the trait bound `for<'de> T: models::_::_serde::Deserialize<'de>` is not satisfied
required because of the requirements on the impl of `DeserializeOwned` for `T`rustcE0277
lib.rs(1, 1): required by a bound in this
de.rs(2500, 8): required by this bound in `from_reader`
blocks.rs(62, 17): consider restricting type parameter `T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't deserialize into "any typed object", only into one which implements either `Deserialize<'de>` or `DeserializeOwned`.

As you don't keep around the JSON, you want to use `DeserializeOwned`:

```
fn read_user_from_file<T, P>(path: P) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    // Open the file in read-only mode with buffer.
    let file = File::open(path)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let t:T = serde_json::from_reader(reader)?;

    // Return the `User`.
    Ok(t)
}
```